# Outlook style keyboard navigation

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a WPF application. Main screen has three sections, on the top the Ribbon control hosts all the commands. On the left ListBox contains some items and on the right content populated based on ListBox.

I want to implement Microsoft Outlook-styled Keyboard/Directional Navigation.
i.e. When I press F6, the focus moves to Ribbon then pressing the Tab key moves the focus inside that Ribbon control. Then pressing F6 moves the focus to ListBox and then pressing F6 again moves to the content Area.

Can someone provide help regarding this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement by handling OnKeyDown on main window abd also PreviewKeyboardFocusLost event to check if losing event is child of other section then mark it handeled to true.